# Why can't I declare Strings in an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio

I am trying to make a C# Class filled with names of TV shows. when I check the right way to do a Srting array online, It appears that I'm doing it right. I'm using Visual studio 2015. When I mouse over the String name, it says "The name DoctorEp does not exist in the current context" When I mouse over the number, it says "Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration." Here's a snippet of my code that should get my point across:

```
Class Names{
String[] DoctorEp = new String[107];
DoctorEp[0] = "rose";
DoctorEp[1] = "the end of the world";
DoctorEp[2] = "the unquiet dead";
DoctorEp[3] = "aliens of london";
DoctorEp[4] = "world war three";
DoctorEp[5] = "dalek";
DoctorEp[6] = "the long game";
DoctorEp[7] = "father's day";
DoctorEp[8] = "the empty child";
DoctorEp[9] = "the doctor dances";
DoctorEp[10] = "boom town";
}
```

Comment: I'm not having any issues. Can you point out where you are having an ussie? Just for info: imo it's better to use an IEnumerable (e.g. List<String>) then an array.

Comment: You've posted a dozen lines of code totally out of any context, and are expecting us to read your mind to see where this code is being used. Please read [mcve] and [edit] your post to provide more information.

Comment: There's really nothing else, that code exists in "Class Names" there's nothing in the main function, it just goes on for 93 more string declarations.

Comment: @RedGeoBlaze please post more code.
Not all the arraylines have to be there. But we need a more specific scope to be able to help

Answer (score 7):

You can't put statements outside a function.

Instead, use an array initializer:

```
String[] DoctorEp = { "rose", ... };
```

Comment: That was My idea, but the string's got 107 members, I've got a few more shows to do that too. It's already written up too, and I just want to know what I'm doing wrong. Like I said, according to tutorials I've seen, That should work

Comment: Your problem is that you can't put executable statements outside a function.

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I'm not too good at remembering Programmer terms. what would you suggest as a fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **instance variables** outside methods, this is not Valid:

```
class Names
{
    string var1 = "abc";
    string var2 = var1;
}
```

**The reason for that is there is no guarantee that the compiler will keep these in order, so in your case you can do the following:**

```
class Names
{
    String[] DoctorEp = new String[]
        {
            "rose",
            "the end of the world",
            "the unquiet dead",
            "aliens of london",
            "world war three",
            "dalek",
            "the long game",
            "father's day",
            "the empty child",
            "the doctor dances",
            "boom town",
        };
}
```

**Or :**

```
class Names
{
    String[] DoctorEp = new String[107];

    public Names()
    {
        InitializeArray();
    }

    void InitializeArray()
    {
        DoctorEp[0] = "rose";
        DoctorEp[1] = "the end of the world";
        DoctorEp[2] = "the unquiet dead";
        DoctorEp[3] = "aliens of london";
        DoctorEp[4] = "world war three";
        DoctorEp[5] = "dalek";
        DoctorEp[6] = "the long game";
        DoctorEp[7] = "father's day";
        DoctorEp[8] = "the empty child";
        DoctorEp[9] = "the doctor dances";
        DoctorEp[1] = "boom town";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the examples show this exact code in a class or in a function?

You have created a class with the variable but then try to work with the variable by setting the strings outside of any class methods (basically method = function as mentioned by @SLaks). You need to do set the values via the array initializer as mentioned by @SLaks or in a class constructor or in a method (function if not in a class) like below (shown using class constructor):

```
class Names {

    string[] DoctorEp = new string[11];

    public Names()
    {
        DoctorEp[0] = "rose";
        DoctorEp[1] = "the end of the world";
        DoctorEp[2] = "the unquiet dead";
        DoctorEp[3] = "aliens of london";
        DoctorEp[4] = "world war three";
        DoctorEp[5] = "dalek";
        DoctorEp[6] = "the long game";
        DoctorEp[7] = "father's day";
        DoctorEp[8] = "the empty child";
        DoctorEp[9] = "the doctor dances";
        DoctorEp[10] = "boom town";
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think it made a difference. I fixed it. thanks.

Comment: So back to what @SLaks stated & I also demonstrated with a class:  You can't have statements outside of a function (method for a class).  In the case of a class, I demonstrated doing this in the constructor.  In the code you just posted, you have declared a method. This "fixes" it as it satisfies this definition. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Now I get it. I can't put declarations like that just in the class. This is my code now. It works just fine.

```
String[] DoctorEp = new String[107];
void DoctorDec()
{
    DoctorEp[0] = "rose";
    DoctorEp[1] = "the end of the world";
    DoctorEp[2] = "the unquiet dead";
    DoctorEp[3] = "aliens of london";
    DoctorEp[4] = "world war three";
    DoctorEp[5] = "dalek";
    DoctorEp[6] = "the long game";
    DoctorEp[7] = "father's day";
    DoctorEp[8] = "the empty child";
    DoctorEp[9] = "the doctor dances";
    DoctorEp[10] = "boom town";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use linq

```
String[] DoctorEp = { "rose", ... }
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat<string>(null, 96))
    .ToArray();
```